# Segue from UICollectionViewCell to right place in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have some images in my `UIScrollView`, and I want that if I click on them, there will be a `UIScrollView` where I can scroll trough all my images (like in the Photo's app). I got this code:

CollectionViewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    //ImageDetailSegue
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ScrollView"]) {
        Cell *cell = (Cell *)sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

        int imageNumber = indexPath.row % 9;

        ScrollViewController *divc = (ScrollViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        divc.img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"full%d.png", imageNumber]];
    }
}
```

ScrollViewController:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"full%d.png", i]]];

    image.frame = CGRectMake((i - 1) * 320, 0, 320, 240);
    [imageScroller addSubview:image];
}
imageScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320 * 6, 240);
```

How can I connect these two?

Comment: What do you mean, "how can I connect the two"? What are you seeing, and what do you want? Is the segue not taking you to the ScrollViewController?

Comment: I don't know how the images from the collectionviewcontroller can appear in my scrollviewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your collection view has, say, 50 images and you click on #5, are you saying you want to see a scroll view, with the same 50 images, but starting at image #5?

Basically, it's all a function of what the model is backing your `UICollectionView` controller. For example, let's say that the collection view has an array (perhaps an array of image names, perhaps an array of objects for which the image filename is one property), like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objects;
```

Then the second scene might have a property that mirrors that, like:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSArray *objects;
```

That first property would be an immutable reference to the main view controller's array that backs its collection view.

Your scroll view should also probably have some index property, so you can tell it which cell you selected:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger index;
```

The second view controller can use this `index` property to figure out where to start its `contentOffset`.

And then the first controller's `prepareForSegue` would look much like you suggested:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ScrollView"])
    {
        Cell *cell = (Cell *)sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

        ScrollViewController *divc = (ScrollViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        divc.objects = self.objects;
        divc.index = indexPath.item;
    }
}
```

Note, I would suggest that neither the collection view nor the scroll view maintain an array of images (because you can quickly run into memory problems). It's much better if it's an array of image names or image URLs. Then you can have `cellForItemAtIndexPath` retrieve the image, as needed, but you then enjoy the full memory efficiency of the collection view. And I'd suggest the scrollview employ a similar technique. (To make life easier on yourself, you might want to contemplate making this second scene a horizontal collection view (where each cell takes up the full screen, itself), or find yourself a good infinite scrolling scrollview class that handles its memory efficiently.)